# Does IntelliJ have the equivalent of the Eclipse "method view"?

Tags: intellij-idea

By this I mean the feature where you can click on a class and the methods are displayed in alphabetical order. At the moment it doesn't seem to drill down any further than class name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or just tell IntelliJ to "Show Members" in Project View. You select it in the upper right by clicking on the gear icon.

Comment: Hardly the same

Answer (score 39):

what you are looking for is `Structure View`. It can be found on the left side below the `Package View` vertical button.

It can also be found under the `Window -> Tool Window` menu item.

- Windows it is the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>.
- macOS it is the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>.
- Linux it is the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. This is in my opinion more useful than to clutter the (already dense) project view.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Structure view can also be moved to the right-side. Hence, you can view Project structure on the left and Methods list on the right.

Answer (score 3):

See view->File structure popup or press ctrl-f12 if you haven't changed the keymap.

It also has call hierarchy (ctrl shift f12 on a method declaration) which is very useful..

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and should be higher up. This is preferable over alt+7 because it doesn't replace the file system hierarchy view with the method hierarchy, and instead puts this same info in a less intrusive popup at the location of your cursor.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X El Capitan and IntelliJ 17, this command will show Method view: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>