# Intellij IDEA Class Files Expanded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, jetbrains-ide

I am having this odd issue in IntelliJ IDEA where the Java class files are automatically expanded by default when I navigate through packages. See the following images:

[image]

[image]

This happened after I downloaded the most recent update, of which I am currently on:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4
Build #IU-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I don't think I made any changes to my configuration, however sometimes I do accidentally use the wrong hotkeys, so it is possible I cmd + shift + random key to toggle this feature on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Original Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740208/does-intellij-have-the-equivalent-of-the-eclipse-method-view)

You should turn off "show members" in project view.

Illustration:

[image]

[image]