# Identify the superclass or interface on which a method is being called in the Java editor of IntelliJ 2018?

Tags: intellij-idea, methods, interface, superclass

Is there a quick easy way to have IntelliJ identify the superclass or interface defining the method being called in a class?

For example, in the following example, the `fireEvent` method is being called on the implicit `this` but this method is not defined within this Java class being edited in IntelliJ 2018.3. Is there some way to ask IntelliJ which of the several interfaces being implemented as well as any parent in the superclass hierarchy defines this particular method?

```
…
private void doIt() {
    …
    fireEvent( event ) ;
}
```

What I am asking is for the opposite of this Question, [*Does IntelliJ have the equivalent of the Eclipse “method view”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6740208/642706). That Question asks “for a given class, what are its methods offered?”. I am asking “for a given method being invoked, from what inherited superclass or interface is that method defined?”.

Answer (score 1):

I generally just context-click (Ctrl-click on PC, Command-click on macOS) to navigate to the source for a method. The `.java` file of the superclass or interface opens in the editor.

In order to avoid navigating away, you can also context-hover. Another option is showing the javadoc via context-q when the cursor is somewhere in the method name.

Comment: As do I. I am looking for a quicker simpler way, perhaps some kind of floating windoid.

Comment: Ctrl-q will bring up the javadoc in a way that I think shows where the definition is.